# django restframework check permission before function

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

Im checking permission before the POST method in an APIView like this:

```
class ResultDataApi(APIView):
...
   authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
   permission_classes = ([permissions.IsAuthenticated, CheckReadPermission])

   def post(self, request):
```

Now I want to check another permission when executing a function inside of the post methode, something like this:

in views.py

```
execute_command_function(...)
```

decorating the function

```
@permission_classes(CheckUpdatePermission, )
def execute_command_function(...)
```

also tried it as in the first step, but not working:

```
permission_classes = ([permissions.IsAuthenticated, CheckReadPermission])
cmd_output_data[cmd_key] = execute_command_function(...)
```

Comment: Permissions are meant to be applied on views e.g. `get`, `post`. When you're inside `post`, you already have the necessary permission to access the view. If you need to check for some other kind of permission from inside `post`, you need to implenent that yourself.

Comment: thats what I actually did. Didnt find another solution for that. Thank you